# Eclipse RCP Preference page configuration (removing incompatible)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I support a RCP Eclipse application. When I started application and open preference pages (Windows -> Preferences) I observed a few properties Items that are not applicable and not needed in my RCP application. I need to have, for example :

- General properties page
- my rcp specific properties page 1
- my rcp specific properties page 2
- my rcp specific properties page 3

But I see a lot of

- General properties page
- my rcp specific properties page 1
- my rcp specific properties page 2
- my rcp specific properties page 3
- Java
- team
- and other properties pages.

Is there a way to remove non-applicable properties from my Application Preferences Dialog?

I use Eclipse Neon.3 on Windows 10

Thank you in advance
Alexander

Comment: Are you actually using Java (Eclipse JDT) and the other things? Just leave them out of the RCP if you don't want them. Use a Target Platform so you can specify exactly what you want in the RCP easiily.

Comment: Yes my IDE based om Eclipse JDT and Xtext

Comment: You may still be able to leave out the JDT UI plugins and the plugins providing the other unwanted pages. Otherwise look at using the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to suppress unwanted pages - this will require some research to find out the page ids.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [activities](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm).

Below some applicable relevant SO questions.

For E3: [RCP exportWizard remove unnecesary items](http://RCP%20exportWizard%20remove%20unnecesary%20items)

For E4: [Hide Coolbar/Toolbar items/Preference pages in Eclipse RCP application (Eclipse e4)](http://Hide%20Coolbar/Toolbar%20items/Preference%20pages%20in%20Eclipse%20RCP%20application%20(Eclipse%20e4))

Comment: links are unavailable

Answer (score 0):

or use preference manager to remove that particular preference node